# Stroke in AChartEngine barchart

Tags: android, achartengine, stroke

How make stroke in AChartEngine barchart?

This dont work for me:

```
mCurrentSeries = new XYSeries("Sample Data");

mDataset.addSeries(mCurrentSeries);

mCurrentRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();

mCurrentRenderer.setStroke(BasicStroke.SOLID);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not supported in AChartEngine yet. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16137039/achartengine-barchart-using-basicstroke-to-add-a-solid-outline) for extra explanations.

Comment: It's possible to make bar spacing 1 pixel?

Comment: You can set the bar spacing to a fraction of the bar width, but you cannot specify the value in pixels.